# javafx 3d sphere partial texture

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I am trying to draw a texture on a sphere with JavaFX (16). I add the material with the texture but the texture is stretched to the whole surface. It is possible to set the texture on only a portion of the surface? Like the image below (not mine, taken from SO):

[image]

My code so far (very trivial):

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
   Sphere sphere = new Sphere(200);
   PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
   material.setDiffuseMap(new Image(new File("picture.png").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()));
   sphere.setMaterial(material);
   Group group = new Group(sphere);
   Scene scene = new Scene( new StackPane(group), 640, 480, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
   scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());
   stage.setScene(scene);
   stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Do you also need to control the extension of the area where the texture is applied?

Comment: Yes, that's will be awesome. Basically, I the best thing will be to put that red square at any coordinate and stretch to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the texture you apply is stretched to the whole sphere is that the texture coordinates that define the `Sphere` mesh are mapping the whole sphere surface, and therefore, when you apply a diffuse image, it is translated 1-1 to that surface.

You could create a custom mesh, with custom texture coordinates values, but that can be more complex.

Another option is to create the diffuse image "on demand", based on your needs.

For a sphere, a 2D image that can be wrapped around the 3D sphere can be defined by a `2*r*PI x 2*r` rectangular container (a JavaFX `Pane` for our purposes).

Then, you can draw inside your images, scaling and translating them accordingly.

Finally, you need a way to convert that drawing into an image, and for that you can use `Scene::snapshot`.

Just to play around with this idea, I'll create a rectangular grid that will be wrapped around the sphere, in order to have some kind of a coordinate system.

```
    private Image getTexture(double r) {
        double h = 2 * r;
        double w = 2 * r * 3.125; // 3.125 is ~ PI, rounded to get perfect squares.

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefSize(w, h);
        pane.getStyleClass().add("pane-grid");
       
        Group rootAux = new Group(pane);
        Scene sceneAux = new Scene(rootAux, rootAux.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth(), rootAux.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());
        sceneAux.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
        SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
        return rootAux.snapshot(sp, null);
    }
```

where `style.css` has:

```
.pane-grid {
    -fx-background-color: #D3D3D333,
    linear-gradient(from 0.5px 0.0px to 50.5px  0.0px, repeat, black 5%, transparent 5%),
    linear-gradient(from 0.0px 0.5px to  0.0px 50.5px, repeat, black 5%, transparent 5%);
}

.pane-solid {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

(based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28875931/3956070))

With a radius of 400, you get this image:

[image: 2D grid]

each square is 50x50, and there are 50x16 squares.

If you apply this diffuse map to an `Sphere`:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PhongMaterial earthMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        earthMaterial.setDiffuseMap(getTexture(400));

        final Sphere earth = new Sphere(400);
        earth.setMaterial(earthMaterial);
    
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

you get:

[image: 3D grid]

In theory, now you could fill any of the grid squares, like:

```
private Image getTexture(double r) throws IOException {
        double h = 2 * r;
        double w = 2 * r * 3.125;

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefSize(w, h);
        pane.getStyleClass().add("pane-grid");

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.RED);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        rectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);
// fill rectangle at 20 x 10
        rectangle.setTranslateX(20 * 50 + 1);
        rectangle.setTranslateY(10 * 50 + 1);
        Group rootAux = new Group(pane, rectangle);
    ...
```

with the result:

[image: 1 rectangle]

Now that you have a well positioned image (for now just a red rectangle), you can get rid of the grid, and simply use a black color for the texture image:

```
   private Image getTexture(double r) throws IOException {
        double h = 2 * r;
        double w = 2 * r * 3.125;

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefSize(w, h);
//        pane.getStyleClass().add("pane-grid");
        pane.getStyleClass().add("pane-solid");
```

resulting in:

[image: black sphere]

Now it is up to you to apply this idea to your needs. Note that you can use an `ImageView` with size 50x50, or 100x100, ... instead of the red rectangle, so you can use a more complex image.

Comment: I try your solution and it works! I didn't know the snapshot trick it is very useful. Basically I understand that you create an equirectangular projection of the sphere and draw the rectangle on it. The only proble is that my rectangle become stretched when go toward the poles. Is it possible to create the texture with the rectangle already prpjected? Or I have to project it by myself?

Comment: If most of your sphere is black, you can always create the rectangle at a more “tropical” position, to avoid stretching, and the rotate the sphere

Comment: In the end, let the user change the x/y/width/height of the red area, so the stretch is no more a problem. Very thanks for your help!